# Change Color Via Console

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, html5-canvas

Im trying to figure out how to change color of the canvas for this site: [Weave silk](http://weavesilk.com/)

Pretty sure the magic happens [Here](http://weavesilk.com/js/site.js)

If you open controls in the top left, there is a color swatch. If i mousedown on that the color of the paint in #sparks changes. I want to replicate that click but within console.

i can console this:

```
$('[clip-path="url(#11)"]').trigger('mousedown');
$('[clip-path="url(#11)"]').trigger('mouseup');
```

But want this:

```
Sparks.color = #123456;
```

Im hoping theres someone on here that familiar with this and can help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well in that code you have to check the value of

```
color = _ref1[i];
```

and then change the code in the variable

```
colors = [['#3e95cc', '#82cefc', '#276f9b', '#3dbbea'], ['#53bf39', '#65eb43', '#53BD39'], ['#e1d730', '#fdf23f', '#E3BF30'], ['#ea5126', '#fd722e', '#EB5126'], ['#db4775', '#fd5e8f', '#dd4876', '#fe495e'], ['#825ba1', '#b585da'], ['#555555', '#717171']];
```

It seems that depends on the iteration of _ref1 variable takes one color or other. Then it use that hex code and add some modifications to create the final color.

Comment: Isnt this used to create the color swatch controller? Its only run once, I want to change the color while mouse is down ( drawing on canvas )